# Error (0x80070002) when dll is not in the same path from registration

Tags: .net, dll, com, assemblies, regasm

First, the question is similar to [Deploying .NET COM dll, getting error (0x80070002)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500931/deploying-net-com-dll-getting-error-0x80070002) but it didn't answer my problem.

I have build a dll (.net4) that I use with VBA in Excel / Word.

**Principle:**

- I register the dll with regasm.exe from a temporary folder (no problem)

  ```
  RegAsm.exe `C:\temp\install\mydll.dll` /codebase
  ```
- When Excel / Word load, the document (excel or word) load the dll in references

  ```
  Call ThisWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromFile("C:\working\anyfolder\mydll.tlb")
  ```

The folderpath can change depending the user (he create documents where he wants), and he can send documents to other users (if the dll is not in the folder, the document works in a degraded mode.

All of this works fine.

**My problem:** Recently I decided to improve the installation of this dll. When the installation finish I add a clean of the installation folder (C:\temp\install). But after doing that, when I try to use my dll in Excel / Word I have the `error 0x80070002 File not found`, even if the dll is in the folder of use (it's the same version of the dll I register)

**What I know:** I understood that he want the dll in the installation folder.

**What I want:**

- Is there a way, after registration with regasm, to delete dll from installation folder and only use the one in the folder of documents (and move the dll from folder to folder depending needs).
- Should I take a look at the GAC ? (I read the GAC wasn't needed if the dll is in the same folder as the document)

I read [regasm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6(v=vs.100).aspx) documentation but found no information about it

If any other information is needed to anwser this, don't hesitate to ask.

Thanks a lot

**update**

To solve my problem, during the installation I add an installation to the GAC

```
(new Publish()).GacInstall("C:\temp\install\mydll.dll")
```

Publish needs a reference to `System.EnterpriseServices`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The COM DLL needs to be present in the folder it was registered from all the time. You *can* use it in any application, but the Windows system needs to be able to find the DLL.

Your specific problem sounds like you should look into Office addin development.

---

There are little exceptions like Microsoft Dynamics NAV 5 that also require the DLL be present in the same folder as the application's executable, but I guess that's just a flaw in design and shouldn't normally be the case (in Dynamics: If you use the COM class both from the classic client and an application server, the COM-DLL needs to be present both in the classic-folder and the application server folder).

Comment: In office the load is okay and in references the dll is not indicated "missing". Like you said I guess it's how the design work. During the installation I add an installation to the gac and now the suppress from installation folder works.

Comment: There's a huge difference between COM references and normal .NET references! Referencing a COM object is very well possible without having the DLL, as information about the interfaces and stuff are taken from the Registry/the TLB file! To reference a .NET DLL in Visual Studio for example, the DLL is required, because all the information about classes and stuff is taken from the DLL itself. The fact that the COM-DLL is missing only gets obvious when Windows actually tries to instantiate the COM class, which then causes the runtime error you got.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I'll search for documentations on com / .net, I don't master the subject and I think it would be needful